# GIT Clone Repository Auth Error Visual Studio for Mac OS

Tags: macos, visual-studio, github

I am trying to clone Remote GIT repo into visual studio 2022 for MAC OS. I am following some guides but could't success, I also try to clone using git generate token but could't success and I also try to modify github keychain Access but no sucess.

following error occurs:-
Cloning into '/Users/888/Projects/'...
error: unable to read askpass response from '/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/GitAskPass'
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://****@gmail.com@github.com': Device not configured

Comment: did you find a workaround for this?